# Consistent removal of nodes from grid_2d_graph

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, networkx

Say that I have a regular 2d grid graph `G` made of `NxN=100x100` nodes. I create such network by calling:

```
N=100
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() ) #Dictionary of all positions
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, labels=labels,with_labels=False, node_size=10)
```

and I get a result similar to that shown in the left hand side of this picture:

[image]

Now, say that my network experiences a disruptive event which renders a number of nodes failed (right hand side of the picture). My graph `G` is no longer made of the same number of nodes: graph `G2` now possesses `K<NxN` nodes. Given this case, I want to be able to draw `G2` by calling:

```
G2=G.remove_nodes_from(failed_nodes_dict) #Failed_node_dict holds the disrupted nodes
nx.draw_networkx(G2, pos=pos, labels=labels,with_labels=False, node_size=10)
```

**My question.** How can I do this, in order to make sure that the dictionary of positions `pos` is not altered? *This means*: if node `0` is in position `(0,0)` (upper left) in situation **1)** and it does not fail, then it must appear in the same position in situation **2)**. This way, the two networks can be comparable in that the second is just a "transformation" of the first. **Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled to see why you were asking this question - the code should basically work exactly as you want already.  However, you have an error which may be what is causing you to ask this question.

```
G2= G.remove_nodes_from(failed_nodes_dict) #Failed_node_dict holds the disrupted nodes
```

This will make `G2` be `None`.  `G.remove_nodes_from(L)` removes the nodes in `L` from `G`.  It doesn't create a new graph that looks like `G`, but without those nodes.  So it doesn't return anything.  Because of this `G2` isn't being given any value.  The graph `G` has had those nodes removed.

So the following should work:

```
N=100
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() ) #Dictionary of all positions
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, labels=labels,with_labels=False, node_size=10)

#find failed nodes here

G.remove_nodes_from(failed_nodes_dict) #Failed_node_dict holds the disrupted nodes
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, labels=labels,with_labels=False, node_size=10)
```

`pos` is never changed in this code.

Comment: Thanks @Joel. Just to make sure I always have my reference graph, how can I make sure that the new graph that is being drawn is not a modified `G`, but something like a modified copy of `G`? I might want to refer to the original `G` in later stages.

Comment: Look into `G.copy()`.  If you aren't already aware, as a general rule, be careful with making copies of things in python.  Sometimes you're just giving the same object a new name, so a change to the object by either name affects both: `a=[1]`, `b=a`, `b.append(2)` makes `a` become `[1,2]`.  In this case I believe `G.copy` will do what you want, but there may be issues if for example an edge has a list of values associated with it and you edit some of those values.  It might change that attribute for both graphs.  You'll want to read up more on it.

Comment: After I changed the line to `nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, labels=labels,with_labels=False, node_size=10)`, it throws an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nodes' 
`. Can't figure out what it is referring to. I'll try to implement the answer below to see if I get rid of this.

Comment: I tried with `len(G)` and it throws out `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`, so my `G` is empty... what went wrong?

Comment: Your first comment is hard to answer without seeing what your code is.  You've got a bug before here where you assign `G` to be `None`: You've probably put a command in like `G=G.remove_nodes_from(...)`  If so, you should change it to `G.remove_nodes_from(...)`.  The issue is that `G.remove_nodes_from(...)` does not return anything.

Comment: Second comment: if `G` has been set to `None`, then `len(G)` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I would extend a bit the answer of @AbdallahSobehy. However, for a more general reusability of `networkx` graphs, I would suggest storing position and label information inside the graph structure, rather than in a separate containers.

Starting with the reduced version of your graph (for `N = 5`):

```
N = 5
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict((n, n) for n in G.nodes())
labels = dict(((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N) for i, j in G.nodes())
```

One can store `pos` and `label` dictionaries as graph attributes:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'pos', pos)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'labels', labels)
```

And use them for ploting:

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'),
                 labels=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'labels'),
                 with_labels=True, node_size=500)
```

[image]

You can later perfom any operation in the graph, such as removing some nodes:

```
G.remove_nodes_from([(0,0),(0,2),(2,2),(2,1)])
```

And replot the graph without actually needing to recalculate `pos` or `label` dictionaries, as the entries are automatically updated with the graph operations. The following line is exactly the same as the plot call above:

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'),    
                 labels=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'labels'), 
                 with_labels=True, node_size=500)
```

But this time, yields a different image:

[image]

In short: store everything you can in node/edge attributes, as they will be automatically updated with graph changes.

Comment: Your hint is fabulous! But I was wondering: is there anything similar to this, if I want to assign a given attribute to the edges as well? For instance, say that I have the length distribution of the edges of another network and would like to create a network with the same positions as the lattice but with its edge lengths coming from a specific distribution. Feasible?

Comment: Btw, I tried your approach and got some troubles. I have a line that says `G=nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)`. So, when I call `nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), labels=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'labels'), with_labels=False, node_size=10)`, it throws out: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'node' `. Is this because the `relabel` line is conflicting?

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani Answering the first question: networkx also has [set/get_edge_attributes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/functions.html#attributes). Additionally, you can set the attribute of a particular edge manually as `g[node1][node2]['attribute'] = value` with `g` as your graph. For the second question, `relabel_nodes` is an *inplace* operation, so it is returning `None` and you are overriding `G` with `None`: replace that line with `nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)` (without assigning the return value to `G`).

Comment: I assume the same applies to `G=G.remove_nodes_from(mydict)`, as this must be another *inplace* operation. And this must explain why I get the same `AttributeError` as before...

Comment: Yes, indeed. I would suggest you check the functions in the [networkx documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/), as its very clear there if they are *inplace* or they return a new copy of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by relabeling nodes from (i,j) to the numbers you see on the figures from the labels dictionary. Then remove the failed nodes. Finally, adjust the pos dictionary to map positions to the new labels of nodes by simply reversing the labels dictionary. Here is what I added after your code:

```
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)
G.remove_nodes_from([0,4,12,18])            
pos = {y:x for x,y in labels.iteritems()}
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 300)
```

for an N = 5 and failed nodes [0,4,12,18], here is the results I got before (left) and after (right) failed nodes are removed.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I like the visualization. But since the disruptive events are of distinct severity time after time, I need a consistent model which tells me if node `0` has failed after event *i*. If I were to change the `pos` dict, I would lose this consistency. The only thing that changes in this model is the loading (the severity of the event) and the behavior of each node, but not their positions or labeling.

Comment: unfortunately I have just discover a bug in my code for plotting the network after failure. I would like to discuss this on chat if you are available sometimes!

Comment: I wouldn't mind but I can not find you on chat, you disappear. try to bookmark the last chat room that we were in. I already sent you a message there: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95121/discussion-between-abdallah-sobehy-and-francesco-castellani